stalk of analytic higher direct image sheaves
What are the stalks of higher direct image sheaves in the analytic setting?
For simplicity, consider a surjective submersion
$\pi: X \to Y$ of compact complex manifolds. Consider an analytic sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$. Is it true that the analytic higher direct images always have stalks
$$
R^k \pi_* \mathcal{F}|_p \cong H^k(X_p, \mathcal{F}|_{X_p})?
$$
Here, $p \in Y$ and $X_p$ denotes the fiber over $p$ and $\mathcal{F}|_{X_p}$ the restriction to this fiber.
For example, I believe that when $\mathcal{F}$ is a constant sheaf such as $\underline{\mathbb{Z}}_X$, we have $R^k \pi_* \underline{\mathbb{Z}}_X|_p \cong H^k(X_p, \underline{\mathbb{Z}}|_{X_p})$. In addition, when $\mathcal{F}$ is $\mathcal{O}_X$, we have $R^k \pi_* \mathcal{O}_X \cong H^k(X_p, \mathcal{O}_{X_p})$. Are these mere exceptions, or does this above claim about stalks always holds true? Do I need to take fibers $R^k \pi_* \mathcal{F} \otimes \mathbb{C}(p)$ instead?

Yes, you needto take fibers. E.g. in the $\mathcal O_X$ case, fhet stalk is a module over the local ring $\mathcal O_{Y,y}$, whereas the cohomology is a finite dimensional vector space.

You seem to be looking for base change theorems.
